# Live URLs completely different from defined ones

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, url-rewrite, ce-1.9.2.0, product-urls

I have an odd problem with a 1.9.2.0 Magento install.

Even though I have specific URLs set for each product, I am seeing the same format for every product, based on one of the initial products we setup:

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/first-product-created-1650
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/first-product-created-1651
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/first-product-created-1652
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/first-product-created-1653
```

The system seems to be using the ID at the end to differentiate, but it is not the product ID.

This is the case whether a direct product link or via categories:

```
http://www.mydomain.co.uk/brands/mybrand/first-product-created-1653
```

I've cleared cache, reindexed, etc. Nothing works.

I've pored over the backend, and am lost as this value is not hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when Magento detects a duplicate rewrite. Could be because of multiple stores (/languages) or identical URLs between products.

If you haven't added custom URL rewrites you can truncate the `core_url_rewrite` table and reindex again to fix it although they might return at some point.

Another downside to that is any URLs indexed by google will return a 404

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the insight. I had different URLs at the default level to the language level.